# Salesforce Connect Custom Adapter test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, lightning-connect, externalobjects, salesforce-connect

What is the correct way to approach testing Salesforce Connect custom adapters? Perhaps there is a unified approach to testing all of its parts, but specifically what is the approach for testing the following items:

- **Provider**:

  - getCapabilities method
  - getAuthenticationCapabilities method
  - getConnection method
- **Connection**

  - constructor
  - sync method
  - query method
  - search method

I assume that we can simply run queries for our external objects for the `query` and `search` methods of the Connection class, which also hits the `getCapabilities` method of the Provider class. With that, I'm assuming we can do a normal web service mock for the test.

What's the best way to approach the rest of these items?