# Code Coverage - Salesforce Connect Custom Adapter / Datasource.Connection Class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, externalobjects, salesforce-connect

I am unable to find documentation on or get any code coverage for the customer adapter Apex Class (Datasource.Connection Class). For awareness, the external data source and customer adapter functions as expected.

In the test class itself, if I create an instance of the external list and then query to populate the list of external objects it only gets to the Datasource.Provider class and stops after the getCapabilities() method. It never gets to the Datasource.Connection class. **No errors are returned.**

Following the approach in this blog post only helps code coverage in regards to other apex classes utilizing external object but does nothing to cover the actual custom adapter (Datasource.Connection) apex class.

Blog Post: http://grahambarnard.com/development/2016/02/08/mocking-external-objects/

I have attempted to directly call the Datasource.Connection class from the test class and mock the DataSource.QueryContext in the query method, but I'm unable to successfully type Datasource.QueryContext correctly or this may not be possible how I would expect. I have also read the System.isRunningTest() answered question approach below, but again this helps with coverage of the class calling the custom adapter, but not coverage of the custom adapter class itself.

Can anybody please direct me to some documentation or other relevant questions on achieving code coverage for the custom adapter Datasource.Connection class?

Related Unanswered Question: [Salesforce Connect Custom Adapter test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218987/salesforce-connect-custom-adapter-test-class)

Related Answered Question: [Test class for a controller that has logic to query the external object records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/test-class-for-a-controller-that-has-logic-to-query-the-external-object-records?rq=1)

**Example of Datasource Connection Class:**

```
global class StackOverflowDataSourceConnection extends
        DataSource.Connection {
    private DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionInfo;

    /**
     *   Constructor for StackOverflowDataSourceConnection
     **/
    global StackOverflowDataSourceConnection(
            DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionInfo) {
        this.connectionInfo = connectionInfo;
    }

    /**
     *   Defines the schema for the external system. 
     *   Called when the administrator clicks “Validate and Sync”
     *   in the user interface for the external data source.
     **/
    override global List<DataSource.Table> sync() {
        List<DataSource.Table> tables =
                new List<DataSource.Table>();

        // Defines columns for the table of Stack OverFlow posts
        List<DataSource.Column> postColumns =
          new List<DataSource.Column>();

        // Defines the external lookup field.
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.externalLookup(
          'owner_id', 'stackoverflowUser__x'));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('title', 255));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('view_count', 255));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('question_id',255));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('creation_date',255));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('score',255));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.url('link'));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.url('DisplayUrl'));
        postColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('ExternalId',255));

        tables.add(DataSource.Table.get('stackoverflowPost','title',
          postColumns));

        // Defines columns for the table of Stack OverFlow users
        List<DataSource.Column> userColumns =
          new List<DataSource.Column>();
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('user_id', 255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('display_name', 255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('location',255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('creation_date',255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.url('website_url',255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('reputation',255));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.url('link'));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.url('DisplayUrl'));
        userColumns.add(DataSource.Column.text('ExternalId',255));

        tables.add(DataSource.Table.get('stackoverflowUser',
                'Display_name', userColumns));

        return tables;
    }

    /**
     *   Called to query and get results from the external
     *   system for SOQL queries, list views, and detail pages
     *   for an external object that’s associated with the
     *   external data source.
     *
     *   The QueryContext argument represents the query to run
     *   against a table in the external system.
     *
     *   Returns a list of rows as the query results.
     **/
    override global DataSource.TableResult query(
            DataSource.QueryContext context) {
        DataSource.Filter filter = context.tableSelection.filter;
        String url;

        // Sets the URL to query Stack Overflow posts
        if (context.tableSelection.tableSelected
.equals('stackoverflowPost')) {
            if (filter != null) {
                String thisColumnName = filter.columnName;
                if (thisColumnName != null &&
                        thisColumnName.equals('ExternalId'))
                    url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                            + 'questions/' + filter.columnValue
                            + '?order=desc&sort=activity'
                            + '&site=stackoverflow';
                else
                        url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                                + 'questions'
                                + '?order=desc&sort=activity'
                                + '&site=stackoverflow';
            } else {
                url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                        + 'questions'
                        + '?order=desc&sort=activity'
                        + '&site=stackoverflow';
            }
        // Sets the URL to query Stack Overflow users
        } else if (context.tableSelection.tableSelected
.equals('stackoverflowUser')) {
            if (filter != null) {
                String thisColumnName = filter.columnName;
                if (thisColumnName != null &&
                        thisColumnName.equals('ExternalId'))
                    url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                            + 'users/' + filter.columnValue
                            + '?order=desc&sort=reputation'
                            + '&site=stackoverflow';
                else
                    url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                            + 'users' + 
'?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow';
            } else {
                url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
                        + 'users' + '?order=desc&sort=reputation'
                        + '&site=stackoverflow';
            }
        }

        /**
         * Filters, sorts, and applies limit and offset clauses.
         **/
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows =
                DataSource.QueryUtils.process(context, getData(url));
        return DataSource.TableResult.get(true, null,
                context.tableSelection.tableSelected, rows);
    }

    /**
     *   Helper method to parse the data.
     *   The url argument is the URL of the external system.
     *   Returns a list of rows from the external system.
     **/
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(String url) {
        String response = getResponse(url);

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows =
                new List<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> responseBodyMap = (Map<String, Object>)
                JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);

        /**
         *   Checks errors.
         **/
        Map<String, Object> error =
                (Map<String, Object>)responseBodyMap.get('error');
        if (error!=null) {
            List<Object> errorsList =
                    (List<Object>)error.get('errors');
            Map<String, Object> errors =
                    (Map<String, Object>)errorsList[0];
            String errorMessage = (String)errors.get('message');
            throw new 
                    DataSource.OAuthTokenExpiredException(errorMessage);
        }

        List<Object> fileItems=
            (List<Object>)responseBodyMap.get('items');
        if (fileItems != null) {
            for (Integer i=0; i < fileItems.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, Object> item =
                        (Map<String, Object>)fileItems[i];
                rows.add(createRow(item));
            }
        } else {
            rows.add(createRow(responseBodyMap));
        }

        return rows;
    }

    /**
     *   Helper method to populate the External ID and Display
     *   URL fields on external object records based on the 'id'
     *   value that’s sent by the external system.
     *
     *   The Map<String, Object> item parameter maps to the data
     *   that represents a row.
     *
     *   Returns an updated map with the External ID and
     *   Display URL values.
     **/
    public Map<String, Object> createRow(
            Map<String, Object> item) {
        Map<String, Object> row = new Map<String, Object>();
        for ( String key : item.keySet() ) {
            if (key.equals('question_id') || key.equals('user_id')) {
                row.put('ExternalId', item.get(key));
            } else if (key.equals('link')) {
                row.put('DisplayUrl', item.get(key));
            } else if (key.equals('owner')) {
                Map<String, Object> ownerMap =
                (Map<String, Object>)item.get(key);
                row.put('owner_id', ownerMap.get('user_id'));
            }

            row.put(key, item.get(key));
        }
        return row;
    }

    /**
     *   Helper method to make the HTTP GET call.
     *   The url argument is the URL of the external system.
     *   Returns the response from the external system.
     **/
    public String getResponse(String url) {
        // Perform callouts for production (non-test) results.
        Http httpProtocol = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndPoint(url);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

**Example Test Class Method:**

```
@isTest
static void stackSuccessTest(){

Test.StartTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new stackoverflowResponseMock());
    List<stackoverflowUser__x> lststackUsers = new List<stackoverflowUser__x>();
    lststackUsers = [select title__c, score__c from stackoverflowUser__x];
Test.StopTest(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instances of the Connection classes and call method on it. Be sure to return a mock response for the API call in getResponse().

code:

```
//sync
StackOverflowDataSourceConnection conn = StackOverflowDataSourceConnection(null);
conn.sync();

//query
 DataSource.QueryContext context = new DataSource.QueryContext();
    context.tableSelection = new DataSource.TableSelection();
    context.tableSelection.tableSelected = 'stackoverflowPost';
    context.tableSelection.filter = new DataSource.Filter();
    context.tableSelection.filter.columnName = 'score';
    context.tableSelection.filter.columnValue = '20';
    context.tableSelection.filter.type = DataSource.FilterType.EQUALS;

    StackOverflowDataSourceConnection aConn = new StackOverflowDataSourceConnection (null);
    aConn.query(context);
```